# Fear of asking girl out - is called ...?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, word-usage, vocabulary

Fear or phobia of asking girl out, fear of rejection(that she would say no or even worse).

Here, Soceraphobia (fear of her father/brother) is not involved.

Mostly guys are feared by most compelling feelings of asking girl out. Some however have overcame such intimidation. What this fear is called? Is there any word sum it up ?

Comment: If the fear is of being rejected, then it's probably *aporripsiphobia,* but no-one's going to know what that is! (I coined it from what I believe is the Greek word for *rejection*.)

Comment: It is called the Bollywood movie syndrome. Bollywood movies are a significant culprit in convincing men that being respectful to women is being shy, and encourages men to harass women on the streets and not be afraid of rejection. And when they face the certain rejection, they are disappointed and blame the woman for not helping them align reality with their Bollywood induced fantasy. And that is when the violence starts.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - I don't think Bollywood movies are popular with men in western cultures, certainly not popular enough to have the influence you describe. Men have been harassing women on the streets since long before Bollywood was a thing. In any case if Bollywood encourages men not to be afraid of rejection then how can "Bollywood syndrome" be the name of a fear of rejection phobia?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask a girl out and have no fear of rejection, you have self-confidence.

If you are scared to ask a girl out, it is probably because you are shy.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ***love-shyness*** colloquially. The person is called a ***love-shy***.

It can be applied to women also but it is usually associated with men. The term can cover the fear of any romantic interaction with the opposite sex.

> - love-shy men are unable to get girlfriends/wives either because they don't know how, or they are too affraid.
> - it means finding it difficult to be assertive in informal situations involving potential romantic or sexual partners. For example, a heterosexual love-shy male will have trouble initiating conversations with women because of strong feelings of anxiety.
>
> [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=love-shy)

---

*Note:* If you want a phobia word, there is *pussyphobia* in slang but I don't recommend using it because it is too slangy and has other connotations as well.

> *Ildan has pussyphobia because he is scared to ask girls out or talk to them.* [[Urbandictionay]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pussyphobia)

Although, the term is used in this article about a man who cannot approach a girl without becoming a nerve wreck from [nyc.barstoolsports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/6217969/The-man-with-phobia-of-women.html) but it is not a serious news site. They got it from a [Telegraph article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/6217969/The-man-with-phobia-of-women.html) and reworded it.

An extreme case can be *gynophobia* (or *gynephobia*):

> ...is an abnormal fear of women, a type of specific social phobia. In the past, the Latin term *horror feminae* was used. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynophobia)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of fear or phobia is also  called:

[Dating anxieties](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/your-zesty-self/201009/dating-anxieties-facing-the-unknown):

> - Dating, by its very nature, is a situation in which two people have not already committed to a permanent relationship. So, for many people, if not most people, dating relationships are experienced as insecure attachments and therefore anxiety producing.

(from psychologytoday.com)

[Phobia of dating](http://www.phobia-fear-release.com/phobia-of-dating.html):

> - When you feel shaky or phobic about various aspects of dating or rejection by your prospective partner. 
>     Often many issues related to phobia of dating can be resolved when you simply ask your partner what to do.

(form www.phobia-fear-release.com)

Answer (score 0):

If this fear of asking a girl out gives *an almost pleasurable sensation of fright:*

Why not-

- [thrill](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/thrill)
- [tingle](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tingle)

Comment: Definitely not... Just, extremely awkwardly, handed a letter to girl I like asking her out...almost died or it felt that way...I'm ok now. I'll be OK even if she says no. The fear of regret was just slightly stronger.